# How to establish a dynamic grid with 2 rows and 2 columns depending on the amount of elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have created a grid that displays 4 elements but in a single row. It roughly looks like the following.

```
  //title is an array of elements
  //max amount of elements is 4 , min is 2
  //elements should be distributed as follows:

  //  title1 | title2   or   title1 | title2  or   title1 | title2
  //  title3 | title4                              title3 |
   
    let titleCols = 12
        if (title && title.length) {
          titleCols = 12 / title.length
    }
    
    return(
    <div className="o-grid">
                  <div className="o-grid__col u-12 u-9@lg u-12@md u-12@sm">
                    {/* title (multi) --> this is where the titles are distributed right now in a single row, but should be 1 or 2 rows */}
                    <div className="o-grid">
                      {title.map(i => <div className={`o-grid__col u-${titleCols}@lg u-${titleCols}@md u-12@sm`}><SCFileHeadTitle multiple={title.length > 1 ? true : false}>{i}</SCFileHeadTitle></div>)}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    {/* red card */}
                  {cardProps && (
                    <div className={`o-grid__col u-1 u-3@lg u-3@md u-3@sm`}>
                      <FileHeadCta {...cardProps} />
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>}
    )
```

How would you go about modifying this to fit into the requirements? Im not sure how to determine when to render a new row without creating a mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 renderMultiTile = (elements: any) => {
    const size = 2
    let res = elements.map((e, i) => {
      return i % size === 0 ? elements.slice(i, i + size) : null;
    }).filter((e) => {
      return e;
    })

    return res.map((el, i) => {
      return (<div className="o-grid">
        {el.map((el2, j) => {
          return (<div className="o-grid__col u-$6@lg u-$6@md u-6@sm">
            <SCFileHeadTitle multiple={elements.length > 1 ? true : false}>{el2}</SCFileHeadTitle>
          </div>)
        })}
      </div>)
    })


  }
```

and then

```
return <div className="o-grid">
              <div className="o-grid__col u-12 u-9@lg u-12@md u-12@sm">
                {/* title (multi) */}
                {this.renderMultiTile(title)}
              </div>
              {/* red card */}
              {cardProps && (
                <div className={`o-grid__col u-1 u-3@lg u-3@md u-3@sm`}>
                  <FileHeadCta {...cardProps} />
                </div>
              )}
            </div>}
```